# how to get value of selected radio buttons in different forms?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have an application which looks something like as shown in picture
[image]

To achieve this I've written some code and here is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janakipriya/hRzZf/). As i think the way which i followed is not a right one, so can anyone please suggest some better way to get something as shown in picture using jquery-mobile, html, javascript. And one more thing is when i click on save button i should able to display the status of every field whether it is accepted or rejected based on the radio button selection.Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/janakipriya/hRzZf/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/hRzZf/2/ it will give you status of check radio

Comment: yeah it can be done you just have to catch all that status and show.

Comment: HI savy as u suggested i updated my code using table and it working perfect. But one issue is when i select the status of 4 items i'm getting status of 7items in alert box instead of 4.I don't know where i went wrong can u please help me. I added my fiddle link above in my question.

Comment: hi savy have u seen my new code u got anything where i'm wrong please help.